# performance of render data through nodejs express template

Tags: node.js, express, templates, variables, render

Sorry about bad English first.

If I pass lots of data through nodejs ejs template, but my .ejs file dont have any template tags, then how would its performance?

If my backend express router write like this...

router/index.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    data = getSomeLargeJsonData(); //A big data up to GB
    res.render('index', data );
});
```

But my frontend page is simple...

index.ejs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I dont have any template tags</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>YA</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

For users browsing this page, will user have to download big data or not?
For nodejs render this page, how will things go?